# $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \frac{a\cos(\frac{ak}{2})}{\pi^2-a^2k^2}e^{i(kx-\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}t)}$

Tags: integration

We are struggling with the following integral:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \frac{a\cos(\frac{ak}{2})}{\pi^2-a^2k^2}e^{i(kx-\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}t)}$$

where a, t and m are real positive constants.

Comment: any own thoughts?

Comment: We tried contour integrals. The problem is that one has to be careful which poles to include and the exponent seems to be divergent for "normal" closures.

Comment: this integral is quite non-trivial, but MIGHT be done. Because i have to leave now, i would suggest you have a look here http://residuetheorem.com/2015/08/07/cauchy-principal-value/ which might give you an idea how to handle such stuff, it MAY be possible to tackle your integral by the same techniques//

Comment: Despite this integral looking really rotten, it does actually converge, since the poles cancel with the zeros of the cosine, and the integrand is $O(k^{-2})$ as $k \to \infty$. You probably want to rotate the contour to either the line $\Re(k)=\Im(k)$ or $\Re(k)=0$—consider what that does to the $e^{ik^2 t/2m}$ term.

Comment: Is x also a constant?

Comment: yes, x is also constant

Comment: I think rotate it to $\Re(k)=-\Im(k)$ so that $-ik^2b$ has negative real part.  Then split the cosine into its two pieces.  Complete the square for $\exp(b(k-c)^2-bc^2)$ for each piece.  Then maybe expand $1/(\pi^2-a^2k^2)$ as a Taylor series, and integrate by parts.

Comment: i have the feeling that the techniques described in the link below will allow you to calculate a solution for ur integral. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412761/another-integral-related-to-fresnel-integrals/1417077#1417077