# Integral similar to fresnel integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fresnel-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-r^2}}{r^2-i\gamma^2} dr = ?$$

I tried the normal semicircular contour integrals, but there is always a problem with the exponential when I close the contour.

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412761/another-integral-related-to-fresnel-integrals) is related, but I can't apply the method used to this case.

Comment: I can't really help you directly. All I did was to use Mathematica and I got: $$\frac{1}{2} \pi  e^{-i \gamma ^2} \left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{-1} \, \text{Erf}\left((-1)^{3/4} \gamma \right)}{\gamma }+\sqrt{\frac{i}{\gamma ^2}}\right)$$ for $\Im(\gamma) + \Re(\gamma) \neq 0$

Answer (score 2):

Did you try a Fourier Transform approach? The Fourier transform of $e^{-r^2}$ is still a gaussian function while the inverse Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{r^2-i\gamma^2}$ is a [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution), hence the problem boils down to computing
$$ I(z)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(zx-x^2\right)\,dx $$
for some fixed $z\in\mathbb{C}$. By completing the square we get:
$$ I(z) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{-z^2/4}\left(1+\text{Erf}\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right)$$
that agrees with Guilherme Thompsons's computation in the comments.