# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln (\sqrt(x) + a) b \exp(-b x) d x$ (where $a$ and $b$ are constants)

Tags: integration

I can not calculate this integration please  help me...

Note that this integral is part of complex dual integration and i must obtain that with constants.
I tried by MATLAB but ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int_0^\infty\ln\left(\sqrt{x} + a\right)b\mathrm{e}^{-bx}dx = -\int_0^\infty \ln\left(\sqrt{x} + a\right)\frac{d}{dx}\mathrm{e}^{-bx}dx
$$
integrating by parts we find
$$
-\left[\mathrm{e}^{-bx}\ln\left(\sqrt{x} + a\right)\right]_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm{e}^{-bx}dx
$$
we have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+a}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{a}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + a} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right]
$$
so ultimately you are trying to solve
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + a}\mathrm{e}^{-bx}dx 
$$
and
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm{e}^{-bx}dx 
$$
This
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\mathrm{e}^{-u}du  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}}
$$
The other integral is not great..

To finish off
$$
\left[\mathrm{e}^{-bx}\ln\left(\sqrt{x} + a\right)\right]_0^\infty = -\ln(a)
$$
Since 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x} \to 0
$$
and 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{x}\to \infty
$$
then we can conclude that the term in the bracket tends to $0$.

Comment: and where is the $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt(x) + a} e^{-b x} dx$ ?

Comment: @MrBlue that is the hard part :-S

Comment: My mean is Why it is not great? the integral is part of another integral and eliminating that can be trouble ...

Comment: @tired Sadly I can not solve this one! MrBlue,  I was trying to show where the whole integral probably breaks down.

Comment: The remaining integral in question reads, after a simple sub,

$$
2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{x+a}e^{-bx^2}=2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-bx^2}-2a\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+a}e^{-bx^2}
$$

A calculation of the last integral might be extracted from here:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412761/another-integral-related-to-fresnel-integrals/1417077#1417077

Comment: @tired If you want to provide a completed answer then go ahead! I did not want to proceed further given the OP said it broke down with Matlab! But alas all excuses, and I enjoyed reading your answer!

Comment: @tired Unfortunately I don't understand this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412761/another-integral-related-to-fresnel-integrals/1417077#1417077

Comment: @MrBlue where exactly you have difficulties?

Comment: @tired It was Goodwin-Staton integral. I find that's solution. Thank you